# LoRaWAN OTAA protocol specification

Tags: c, stm32, hal, lora, lorawan

I'm trying to implement communication between LoRaWAN and module using RFM95W with STM32L476. The problem I'm facing is that there is no library for dealing with OTAA and I wasn't able to find any relevant source how it looks like or how it works. Now I'm just able to send raw packets. It would be better if I coded the communication myself but I'm ok with working library, thanks

This protocol uses DevEUI AppEUI and AppKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many libraries for stm32 for LoRa. For myself I go with the official [LoRaMac-node](https://github.com/Lora-net/LoRaMac-node) from semtech. If your starting the journey into C and STM32, you can just start with the [mbed-os](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-lorawan).

Comment: Where is set what SPI my MCU uses?

Comment: @g_1_k I have a feeling you just start with it, and I should say welcome to the world of embedded programming. If `i-cube-lrwan` is pure pain, there is much more purest pain waiting for you in every corner. STM has just great reference manuals and application notes, for all their products, STM32L476 has several hardware supported SPI interfaces, not counting - you can make any gpio an software SPI. All docs are available on their site.

Comment: On the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/02/35/09/0c/4f/f7/40/03/DM00083560.pdf/files/DM00083560.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00083560.pdf) for your mcu on page 1442 is the supported hardware SPI interface for mcu described. Yes, you should read it. As far as I remember, `i-cube-lrwan`  is just `LoRaMac-node` with rewritten hardware abstraction layer by the STM team. No difference. I got stick with LoRaMac-node and purging from the semtech HAL callbacks is pain.

Answer (score 1):

To start to play with LoRaWAN protocol and demo board, there are two mains ways:

- Use the LoRaWAN stack from ST and ST projects : use ST-cube: https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/i-cube-lrwan.html
- Use the LoRaWAN stack provides by Semtech (for information Semtech is the provider of the IP of the radio LORA and radio chip(as SX1276)) and pre-configured projects : https://github.com/Lora-net/LoRaMac-node

For the demo, you can use the ST demo board B-L072Z-LRWAN1 :https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/b-l072z-lrwan1.html .

Don't forget, to use the LoRaWAN protocol, you must be compliante with ETSI(for europe) or FCC(for USA) regulation(frequency plan to use, duty cycle to respect, radio power to respect..)

And To use a LoRaWAN device, the message sent by the device is received by a LoRaWAN gateway (provided by apublic operator (like Orange or Objenious in France, Senet in USA) or by a private network( your gateway with your server), or a by community gateway like TTN)

TTN(The Thing Network) is also a good provider of demo board and server + gateway to start to play with LoRaWAN : https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/

All LoRaWAN specifications are hosted by the LoRa Alliance: https://lora-alliance.org/

Have a good LoRaWAN XP!

Answer (score 0):

Really? No libraries? Check it out https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/i-cube-lrwan.html